# Integrate Facebook comments into a blog

Tags: facebook, facebook-integration

I'm using Facebook as a channel to market job postings on my job board. Whenever a new job posting is added to the site, the site updates Twitter, and Facebook pulls in tweet to show in the Facebook feed.

There's frequently a discussion about the job posting happening on Facebook in the form of comments. Is there a way to bring in that discussion back over to my site, in a reasonably automatic way? I'd love for those comments to appear everywhere (both on my site and on Facebook) and I'd love users to be able to comment from anywhere (both on the site and on Facebook).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Facebook Connect Comment Box. Installation instructions are described here:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/198